# Map is not showing in Carto

Tags: carto

I've created a map in Carto.com with two layers and two widgets. In the builder everything looks fine but somehow this map is not showing anything after I published the map. Find a link: https://wash-liberia.carto.com/builder/d358cebe-2f32-4fc1-bd96-feb0acec15e7/embed

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please could you provide further details to help users solve your problem? Perhaps provide a screenshot of the settings you are using in the builder

Comment: Try to update again the map.